# Firefox does not load new location

Tags: ubuntu, firefox

Currently I'm using **Ubuntu 18.04.5** with **Mozilla Firefox 86.0** in safe-mode, when I provide a new location nothing happens. There is no error page or error message, It does not work when I do google.com or when I select a bookmark, or even go to about:preferences. Chrome does work fine, and I tried re-installing without result. Does anyone know how I can fix this problem or provide some keywords to search for people with the same problem?

Same holds for Mozilla Firefox 88.0a1.
Same holds for a newly created profile via `firefox -P`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-installed Citrix Workspace, but now without `App protection`. It somehow affected Firefox, although Firefox was running outside Citrix.